# Remove a dropdown attribute value from a product

Tags: magento-1.7, product, attributes

I have a custom product attribute that gets populated from a csv import. If the relevant field has a value, that value is applied to the product's attribute. However if that field is empty, the value should be removed. This is what I currently have, but it's not removing the value:

```
if (trim($prod[$fields['SOPDiscountCode']]) != ''){
    $newproduct->setProductDiscountCode($discounts[$prod[$fields['SOPDiscountCode']]]);
}else{
    $newproduct->setProductDiscountCode(0);
}
```

I'm not sure of the correct way to remove the value:

```
$newproduct->setProductDiscountCode('');
```

or

```
$newproduct->setProductDiscountCode();
```

for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$newproduct->unsetProductDiscountCode();
```

or

```
$newproduct->setProductDiscountCode(null);
```

One of those should do the trick.